# How to make a batch file to change short date setting windows

Tags: windows, batch, windows-server-2016

Short date setting on Windows in RDS environment does not meet one of the users requirements. It is MM/dd/YYYY and should be changed in dd/MM/YYYY. How can this be achieved? Is it possible in a batch-file. After modification an application should automatically start.

Or, is another way preferrable, if yes, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The date format is found in the registry at key
`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\International`,
item named `sShortDate`.

You may change it in batch by the command:

```
reg add "HKCU\Control Panel\International" /f /v sShortDate /t REG_SZ /d "dd/MM/yyyy" >nul
```

Or via a `.reg` file containing:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\International]
"sShortDate"="dd/MM/yyyy"
```

Comment: This works exactly as described, thank you very much.